# Draw bitmap texture on EGLSurface for encoding with android MediaCodec

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

I might be re-asking a question that was already in:
[Render Bitmap frames to Surface for encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470134/render-bitmap-frames-to-surface-for-encoding)

I need to essentially do the same thing but it's not clear to me whether the main question was solved or not, which is how to render the generated texture on to a Surface. I've looked through the grafika project but it seems to assume that a SurfaceTexture is available, from which it gets the transform matrix for drawing. I've also looked at EncodeAndMuxTest but I cannot figure out how to run it with a bitmap input.

Comment: Sounds like you've got the MediaCodec part, and just need the GLES part?  Some activities in Grafika generate textures and render them, e.g. "hardware scaler exerciser" and "glTexImage2D speed test".  Others record the GL output, e.g. "record GL app".

Comment: Thanks much! After looking over Grafika some more over the weekend, I was able to figure it out. I used the FullFrameRect class to handle the GLES part.

Comment: @PeeVee75 can you please show example?