# Saving video frame from GPU texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

I am attempting to use the GPU to do video processing. I have been so far successful in extracting the frames from a video, and processing them using the GPU. 
Please keep in mind that i'm a total OpenGL noob.

I have come across the following bottleneck however: getting the finished frame from the GPU and recording it into a video.

I am aware of [this](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt) example, but it doesn't exactly suit my needs.

My openGL context is *javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLContext*, which prevents me from sharing textures between the one described by Bigflake's example and mine, which contains the texture i wish to write to the video.

Is there any way to feed the MediaCodec encoder data directly from the GPU? From my research it seems that one can only set a surface provided by the encoder itself as a source using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#createInputSurface()) method.

Can I somehow draw my texture onto the surface provided by the encoder?

I will try to provide any additional details upon request.

Comment: Do you mean - you do not have control over the EGL context creation step (ie  EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID flag cannot be added in the current config) ?

Comment: Two different contexts are needed with different configurations. One for extracting and processing frames, and one for writing the new movie file. I can not share textures between the two.

Comment: Why do you need two contexts with different configurations? Do not conflate EGLSurface with Surface, they are independent.

Comment: @fadden In the EncodeAndMuxTest that i am attempting to use the context is setup using EGL14.eglCreateContext(), returning an android.opengl.EGLContext.

In the ExtractMpegFramesTest that i have used for extracting the frames and processing on the GPU, the context is defined like so: (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL().eglCreateContext, that returns a javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLContext.

I figure that the first context is needed for the swapBuffers method and EGLExt.eglPresentationTimeANDROID

Comment: Per your reference to a linked example that doesn't fit your needs: you're unable to use the `share_context` parameter of `eglCreateContext` to establish resource sharing between the two contexts?

Comment: No, as I've stated above, the two contexts I am creating for each task are different and can't be passed as the share_context parameter. I have tried.

Comment: There are two versions of http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest , one that uses EGL 1.0, one that uses EGL 1.4. There is no reason you can't use EGL 1.4 for everything. Underneath it's a single GLES driver context; the choice of API version doesn't change that. Create one context with the flags you need for both (e.g. make sure EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID is defined) and just use that.

Comment: Oh, yes i haven't considered the second example. Thank you for the pointer @fadden. I will post the results as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up replacing my EGL10 Context with an EGL14 one as @fadden suggested.

I then shared this context with the one created by the CodecInputSurface like in [this](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt) example.

The most important step was rendering the shared texture to the surface defined by the second context. I did this with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27849816/3738533) answer.

I hope that this can be of help to anybody else, i will attempt to clarify if requested.

Thanks again to fadden for his help :).